# What is Dynamic Line Managment

Tags: vdsl

I have a Chorus (NZ Line tech) guy coming out on Friday, as I've signed up to VDSL.

What I want to know is what is DLM exactly, why is it there, and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is Dynamic Line Managment

The explanation below is for DSL but VDSL will use something very similar.

The key parts are:

> A Dynamic Line Management System is all the hardware devices and other components required to monitor customers lines for signs of broadband instability, and then apply software configuration changes in order to keep the line stable.

and:

> Rate Adaptive DSL broadband will connect as fast as line conditions
>   will allow.  However, there are times when lines become unstable due
>   to noise factors.  Every time a DSL connection re-syncs to the
>   exchange, the parameters change and sync speeds can vary.   Noise
>   causes errors such as CRCs & Errored Seconds which can cause the
>   connection to become slow & laggy, or even drop out completely.

---

#### What is a Dynamic Line Management (DLM) system?

> A Dynamic Line Management System is all the hardware devices and other
>   components required to monitor customers lines for signs of broadband
>   instability, and then apply software configuration changes in order to
>   keep the line stable.
>
> The DLM system is independent from, yet supplemental to DSL technology
>   and helps to ensure that DSL broadband lines don't consistently drop
>   when line conditions change.
>
> All UK ISPs have some sort of DLM.  Sky & TalkTalk LLU have their own
>   DLM systems but most other ISPs will use the BT Wholesale DLM.
>   Customers with Sky Fibre and TalkTalk Fibre will also use the BT
>   Wholesale DLM.
>
> **Why do we need Dynamic Line Management?**
>
> Rate Adaptive DSL broadband will connect as fast as line conditions
>   will allow.  However, there are times when lines become unstable due
>   to noise factors.  Every time a DSL connection re-syncs to the
>   exchange, the parameters change and sync speeds can vary.   Noise
>   causes errors such as CRCs & Errored Seconds which can cause the
>   connection to become slow & laggy, or even drop out completely.
>
> Interleaving and/or increasing the SNR Margin can help overcome line
>   instability, but because all lines are different there is no one
>   single one size solution that fits all.   The DLM monitors your line
>   and applies the parameters that it deems necessary to suit your line
>   conditions and maintain stability.
>
> The aim of a DLM system is to maximise a connection’s data rate and
>   throughput speed, whilst maintaining stability of the line.
>
> **How does the DLM monitor your line?**
>
> There are several key components to BT Wholesale's DLM system.  These
>   comprise of:
>
> - DLM Management Device (RAMBo)
> - Element Managers
> - NCAS/OSS - Network Configuration & Assignment System and Operational Support System.

You can read the [source link](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/DLM_system.htm) for a detailed descrition of eaach of these components.

[image]

Source [Dynamic Line Management (DLM) System](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/DLM_system.htm)